# unable to call static function on ES6 class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, static

I have a file called `helpers.js` in the 'helpers' folder. The contents are like below:

```
class Helpers {
    constructor(config) {
        if (this._singleton) {
            throw new Error('A singleton has already been created.');
        }

        this._singleton = this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the singleton object.
     * @returns {Helpers}
     */
    static getSingleton() {
        return this._singleton;
    }
}

module.exports = Helpers;
```

Then in `/helpers/user.js` I want to get the helper's singleton instance.
This is my code:

```
const helpers  = require('../helpers').getSingleton();
```

or

```
const Helpers  = require('../helpers');
const helpers  = Helpers.getSingleton();
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
TypeError: require(...).getSingleton is not a function
```

or

```
TypeError: Helpers.getSingleton is not a function
```

If I hover over `Helpers` in VSCode, I get this tooltip

[image: Helpers Tooltip]

And, whenever I hover over `getSingleton()` I get this tooltip:

[image: getSingleton() tooltip]

So the path is correct, but it still gives me the errors.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you have: `helpers/helpers.js` and `helpers/user.js`, so you'd want to `require('./helpers')` or `require('./helpers.js')`. Assuming this isn't the issue, then what does `console.log(typeof Helpers)` give? What about `console.log(typeof Helpers.getSingleton)`?

Comment: Even if you didn't get the error, the code would not work. `this` inside the static method refers to something different than `this` inside the constructor. Also this is not how singletons work. `getSingleton()` would have to instantiate a new instance (the first time it's called) and return that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to implement the singleton pattern in JavaScript is to just not export the class at all, e.g.

```
class Helpers {}

let helper;
module.exports = function() {
   if (!helper) helpers = new Helpers();
   return helper;
};

// loaded with
var helpers = require('../helpers')(); // note the extra () to call it
```

or even better, since we aren't restricted to Java-like behavior, just skip the function entirely and do

```
class Helpers {}
module.exports = new Helpers();

// loaded with
var helpers = require('../helpers');
```

but *then* if all your module is exporting is a single instance of a class, there's very little reason to use a class in the first place. You might as well do

```
exports.helperMethodOne = function(){};
exports.helperMethodTwo = function(){};
exports.helperMethodThree = function(){};

// loaded with
var helpers = require('../helpers');
```

or

```
module.exports = {
  helperMethodOne() {},
  helperMethodTwo() {},
  helperMethodThree() {},
};

// loaded with
var helpers = require('../helpers');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your require statement is wrong, but its hard to tell you precisely the right syntax without knowing your environment.

`const config = require('/path/to/file');`

Is typical. So try:

`const Helpers  = require('../helpers');`

You wrote `'../helpers.js'` in your screenshot, not `'../helpers'`

You get the error:

> TypeError: require(...).getSingleton is not a function

Because `require(...)` resolves to something else, like `null`, and `null.getSingleton` is not a function.

---

Also, you cannot reference `this` meaninfully inside a static context. `this` ought to only be used for class instances, not static members.

Comment: I've tried both `../helpers` and `../helpers.js` but it shouldn't make a difference from what I've seen and used.

Comment: And by the way, if the `require()` returned null, shouldn't it give me a `cannot read property 'getSingleton' of undefined` error?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to use it as `Singleton.getInstance()`;

```
class Singleton {
    static instance = new Singleton();
    static getInstance = () => Singleton.instance;

    constructor() {
        throw new Error('Use Singleton.getInstance()');
    }
}

module.exports = Singleton;
```

or even something more sneaky and use it as `new Singleton()`

```
class Singleton {
    static instance;
    constructor() {
        if (!Singleton.instance) {
            Singleton.instance = this;
        }
        return Singleton.instance;
    }
}

module.exports = Singleton;
```